# getting error while creating register page with apache, hibernate spring and postgresql

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, postgresql-9.1

I am using Spring- hibernate - postgresql db. When I create register page I'm getting following error while running my app in Apache server:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
        type Exception report
        message Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
        description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
        exception
        javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    root cause

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
        org.hibernate.util.SimpleMRUCache.init(SimpleMRUCache.java:71)
        org.hibernate.util.SimpleMRUCache.<init>(SimpleMRUCache.java:55)
        org.hibernate.util.SimpleMRUCache.<init>(SimpleMRUCache.java:50)
        org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.<init>(QueryPlanCache.java:65)
        org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:176)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:793)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:715)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:189)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 logs.

    Apache Tomcat/8.0.30


    my spring dispatcher code is
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


          <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.studentadmissioncontroller" />
          <mvc:annotation-driven/>

          <bean id="viewResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
                <property name="prefix">
                    <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
                </property>
                <property name="suffix">
                    <value>.jsp</value>
                </property>
         </bean>

         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
                <property name="driverClassName"  value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>  
                <property name="url" value="dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"></property>  
                <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>  
                <property name="password" value="password"></property>  
            </bean>  

            <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  



                <property name="hibernateProperties">  
                    <props>  
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>  
                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

                    </props>  
                </property>  
            </bean>  

            <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
            </bean>  


        </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clearly telling that the one of the dependency is missing in classpath, which is in this case is *org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LRUMap*. So add the apache collection jar in the classpath, if it is maven add the following,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```